# strange behavior on display|display:none elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom modal dialogue that consists of a simple div and some css. There are 2 buttons (OK, CANCEL) buttons. The CANCEL button is always the same; it hides the modal dialogue via `onclick="$('#div').css('display','none')"` (NB: this is also how the modal is shown; `('display','')`). I assign different actions to the OK button depending on the need. This is done via `$('#okBTN').attr('onclick','my_function()')`.

*It works, but only the first time* ©

The first time I open the modal and walk through the steps, everything works as expected. If I close the modal, however, then re-open it, the OK button has **no** action on it. I mean, the onclick is assigned (correctly); it's in the source code, and it will alert correctly via `.attr('onclick')`, but clicking the button does nothing. I have it set that when the modal pops up, the `onclick` is assigned each time; but it's almost as if there is a shadow copy or something stuck in memory or the DOM. Although, I don't see anything strange in Firebug....

I've tried cloning the button, reassigning it, then `replaceWith`'ing. I've also tried `remove`'ing it and re-adding it...

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to say it my friend but you're not leveraging the benefits of jQuery.

- Why set display via CSS?  Just use .hide() .show() or .toggle().
- Why are you setting on onclick attribute via javascript?  This doesn't make much sense at all.  Use $(elem).click(my_function);

The second bullet will likely fix your problem, but I'd do some serious re-evaluation.

Good luck!

Comment: 1) OK. 2) because the `bind` and `click` handlers aren't behaving as expected. thanks.

Comment: If the default handlers aren't working, it might point to another issue in your JS or markup that's preventing them from running or binding correctly.  We'd need to take a peak at your larger source to assess that; however, check out the W3C's validation utilities and your favorite JS debugger to find issues in your markup.

Comment: @Adam Terlson : thanks for the input. I've tried running through with firebug et. al. and still can't figure it out. If you want to gander, you can see what I mean at kaliedos.com/sample; enter an email address (just make one up, but follow convention asdfg@sdfgfgb.com), click "confirm", then in the pop-up enter 3 random letters, click "ok", then "cancel". Go through those steps again... this time you will see the alert from the 'OK' function twice. Keep repeating, and the alert multiplies....

Comment: The issue is that jQuery's click events are really a queue of functions.  When you bind a click event, it's adding the function to the queue.  Because you're declaring your click (line 159) when you show your modal, every time you show it you're adding another click event.  Do this: `$('#modal_ok_btn').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){conf_code_check()});`  This would be avoided by an architecture that's more in line with jQuery's model and events, such as binding your click events up front or using `live` or `delegate` for AJAX content.

Comment: Well I was using `bind` because `click` didn't seem to be working correctly. So if I were to assign the modal button functions via `.click()` instead of `bind()`, the problem should be resolved? Or is the `unbind/bind` method more likely to work? i.e. does `click` *not* add a click event to the queue? And what exhausts said queue? The modal `bind` added the 'ok' function to the queue when called, but why didn't clicking 'ok' then remove it from the queue? Big thanks!

Comment: [edit]: I changed all of them to `click` instead of `bind`--same thing is happening...

Comment: `.click()` is equivalent to `.bind('click', ...)` in terms of function.  The `.unbind()` is what should fix your issue.  Put it before all of your click binds that don't happen in your document.ready.  I'm not sure what you mean by "what exhausts said queue?"  It's not a queue that's removed when you click on something.  That'd mean you needed to constantly rebind.  You're adding stuff to a queue that persists across clicks, so every time you click on a button with multiple click events, all of them will be called unless one returns false or calls `e.stopPropagation`.

Comment: Gotchya.. so it's not that there was a queue waiting to be used up per say, but rather there were multiple click events being added to a queue that is called via `click`. Thanks for the example, clear answer, patience, and help.

Comment: You're welcome, good sir.  Best of luck.  Keep looking at code samples and reading best practices.  You'll master jquery fu in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind` or event-name binders:

```
$('#okBTN').click(my_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using `.css('display','block')` instead of `.css('display','')`, as assigning a blank `display` value doesn't seem like a good idea (it might work, but just to be safe).

Have you tried setting the `.bind()` function of the element?

```
$('#okBTN').bind('click', my_function);
```